# ios device phone number policy

Tags: ios, phone-number

I've spent the last few hours determining that I am not able to retrieve the phone number from the iOS device.

1. Where in the policy does it disapprove retrieving the device phone number? (my interpretation of the policy is that its ok to use the phone number as long as its used as part of your service and you have the users consent)
2. Are their methods to automatically pull the device phone number? (I found 2 deprecated methods but nothing for > iOS 6)

Comment: Can you share link for the deprecated methods?

Comment: Grabbing a users phone number through ios was available through the SBFormattedPhoneNumber sorry I didn't get the link. Apparently many marketing people were abusing this library and it became deprecated after that. Feel free to fact check :)

Comment: Ah. I see `SBFormattedPhoneNumber` key/value data has been removed from the NSUserDefaults object as of 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no policy disapproving retrieving the phone number because there is no way to get the phone number directly.
2. There is no way to get it without asking the user for it.

There is no valid reason to ask a user for their phone number. Why do you think you need it? No app should require a phone number to function.

Comment: Ill accept the answer because you were correct. Just your statement of no valid reason to to pull it is false. :)